# Deploy to my server with Git

Tags: python, django, git

I have a development of a django project on my day-to-day laptop. Now I have put together a server with Ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn with postgreSQL.

I have pip't git on both my laptop and server. And done a 'git init' in my project on the laptop.

Now I am trying to push/deploy this on my local server.

I have done tons of commands that, more or less, look like this

```
git push --set-upstream ssh://admin@192.168.1.240/home/admin/Django/ master
```

Do not think I have to say that I am new to all this exciting stuff. It is very interesting, but now my head is foggy and I am stuck.

Pointers in right direction are much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to add and commit to the current local repo. Try 'git add' and 'git commit' for that.

Next, add the remote "server" machine, use "git remote add", such as:

```
git remote add origin 192.168.1.240:/home/admin/Django
```

Finally use the 'git push' command to push the local to the remote:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Yes I have done `git add --all` on the local dev machine. Now tried with your suggestion to remote add. No errors, but it does not show on server. Is it really possible to just do it like that. No password for 'admin'?

Comment: In my earlier response, I didn't explain that the 'git push' was still necessary after a 'git add'. I have now updated the answer. You still need to use an ID/PW but that's not really about git more about the method you're using to connect (i.e. ssh). I'd recommend placing your ssh public key on the remote server.